# Numpy Indexing and creation of new array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to understand what is going on inside the print statement.
I know indexing is taking place to create a 2D array however, I don't understand the order

```
x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.001)
X = np.concatenate(([x], [np.ones(y.shape[0])]), axis=0)

print(X[[[0,1],[0,1]],[[0,0],[-1,-1]]])
```

Produces:

```
array([[0.   , 1.   ],
       [6.283, 1.   ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked into [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and I think following example from there should explain that indexing:

*From a 4x3 array the corner elements should be selected using advanced indexing. Thus all elements for which the column is one of [0, 2] and the row is one of [0, 3] need to be selected. To use advanced indexing one needs to select all elements explicitly. Using the method explained previously one could write:*

```
x = array([[0, 1, 2],
           [3, 4, 5],
           [6, 7, 8],
           [9, 10, 11]])
rows = np.array([[0, 0],
                 [3, 3]], dtype=np.intp)
columns = np.array([[0, 2],
                    [0, 2]], dtype=np.intp)
x[rows, columns]
```

last line give

```
array([[0, 2],
       [9, 11]])
```

code in your question seems to do same operation (but with other values) as that example, but with slamming indices directly rather than creating `rows` and `columns`.

`X[[[0, 1], [0, 1]], [[0, 0], [-1, -1]]]` might be readed as get elements which are, counting from `0`: (in `0`th or `1`st row) and (in `0`th or last column)